# how to open url in new tab by making changes in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to open link in new tab .

> ```
> <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Visit Here</a>
> ```

This is the way i can open in new tab changing the tag.But i want to open in new tab by changing css. I tried using

```
target-name:new;
target-new:tab;
```

but this is not working .Can some one tell me how to open href in new tab by changing in css.

Comment: CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheets which gives only **style** not functionalities ,use javascript for your purpose

Comment: or Can i do it using javascript ?

Comment: Why don't you search OP ? That's pretty easy to find with JS

Comment: I suggest you update your question if javascript is an acceptable

Answer (score 1):

try this for jquery..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a").each(function()
 {
  $(this).attr("target","_blank");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: no need for the `each` this could just be `$('a').attr('target','_blank');`

Comment: Ya i have done using above code its working .thank you very much.